# Concise way to split a string into a list of fixed number of tokens

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a piece of code that needs to split a hyphen delimited string into at most three tokens. If there are less than three tokens after splitting, it should append sufficient number of empty strings in order to make three tokens.

For example, `'foo-bar-baz'` should be split to `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`, but `foo-bar` should be split to `['foo', 'bar', '']`.

Here is the code I wrote.

```
def three_tokens(s):
    tokens = s.split('-', 2)
    if len(tokens) == 1:
        tokens.append('')
        tokens.append('')
    elif len(tokens) == 2:
        tokens.append('')
    return tokens

print(three_tokens(''))
print(three_tokens('foo'))
print(three_tokens('foo-bar'))
print(three_tokens('foo-bar-baz'))
print(three_tokens('foo-bar-baz-qux'))
```

Here is the output:

```
['', '', '']
['foo', '', '']
['foo', 'bar', '']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz-qux']
```

My question is that the `three_tokens` function I have written seems to be too verbose for this little task. Is there a Pythonic way to write this, or is there some Python function or class meant especially to do this kind of task that makes the code more concise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple `while` loop:

```
def three_tokens(s):
    tokens = s.split('-', 2)
    while len(tokens) < 3:
        tokens.append('')
    return tokens
```

or extend the list with a calculated number of empty strings:

```
def three_tokens(s):
    tokens = s.split('-', 2)
    tokens.extend([''] * (3 - len(tokens)))
    return tokens
```

or use concatenation so you can put it in the return statement:

```
def three_tokens(s):
    tokens = s.split('-', 2)
    return tokens + [''] * (3 - len(tokens))
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be overkill, but you could use a few methods from `itertools`.

```
list(itertools.islice(itertools.chain(s.split('-', 2), itertools.repeat('')), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
def three_tokens(s):
    t1, unused, t2 = s.partition('-')
    t2, unused, t3 = t2.partition('-')
    return [t1, t2, t3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work.

```
tokens = s.split('-', 2)
tokens += [''] * max(0, 3 - len(tokens))
```

Comment: No need for `max()`; the limit on `s.split()` makes sure there never are more than 3 elements in `tokens` in any case.

Comment: Besides, multiplying a list by a negative number results in an empty list as well; the `max()` is entirely overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> n = 3
>>> a = '123-abc'
>>> b = a.split('-', n)
>>> if len(b) < n-1:
...     b = b + ['']*(n-len(b))
...
>>> b
['123', 'abc', '']
>>>
```

Comment: Why the `if` statement and the `b[:]` copy? `[''] * 0` is an empty list, and the list-copy-by-slice is entirely redundant and a waste of cycles.

Comment: Yes. b[:] is not required. b+['']*max(1,2-len(b)) should do the trick.

Comment: See my [comment on another answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308761/concise-way-to-split-a-string-into-a-list-of-fixed-number-of-tokens/22308969#comment33898474_22308930), you don't need `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def three_tokens(s):
    tokens = s.split('-', 2)
    return [tokens.pop(0) if len(tokens) else '' for _ in range(0, 3)]
```

...yields

```
>>> three_tokens('foo')
['foo', '', '']

>>> three_tokens('foo-bar')
['foo', 'bar', '']

>>> three_tokens('foo-bar-baz')
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

>>> three_tokens('foo-bar-baz-buzz')
['foo', 'bar', 'baz-buzz']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def three_tokens(s):
    output = ['', '', '']
    tokens = s.split('-', 2)
    output[0:len(tokens)] = tokens
    return output
```

One more oneliner:

```
three_tokens = lambda s: (s.split('-', 2) + ['', ''])[:3]
```

BTW, I don't find anything un-pythonic with your solution. It is a bit verbose but the intent is very clear.

One more:

```
def three_tokens(s):
   it = iter(s.split('-', 2))
   return [ next(it, '') for _ in range(3) ]
```